# How to use 'useParams()' inside of axios API Call?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Good morning,

I'm trying to make an API call using axios but with a variable inside the string url.

```
function MarqueDetails() {
let { marqueName } = useParams();
console.log({marqueName})
const [marqueDetails,setMarqueDetails] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/brand/` + {marqueName})
    .then(response => {
        setMarqueDetails(response.data)
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })

}, []);
```

The problem is the variable returns a very weird object string when i make the call with the variable `{marqueName}`

[image]

I know that the problem has to do something with the variable `{marqueName}` that i'm pulling from the request using `useParams` from `react-router-dom` but i don't know how to fix it.

Thank you in advance !

P.S : the API url in the picture is not working, i just noticed it and i fixed it but i still have the problem with the `[object20%Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template literal syntax is incorrect.  When referencing a variable in the template you need to use the dollar sign.

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/brand/${marqueName}`)
    .then(response => {
        setMarqueDetails(response.data)
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })

}, []);
```

Comment: No prob!  If you can accept the answer as correct that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
'http://localhost:5000/brand/' + {marqueName}
```

If we try to decompose this expression we get 'add string to object' since `marqueName` variable is inside brackets.

[image]

what you want instead is

```
'http://localhost:5000/brand/' + marqueName
```

Comment: You're right, but the answer above is more detailed, the problem was about literal syntax